# How to replace value of a key in maven

Tags: maven, maven-replacer-plugin

I have a simple property file, containing the following lines:

```
abc=123
location=C:\temp
version=1.0.0
```

Now, using some Maven plugin, I need to change the value of `version` from `1.0.0` to some other value.

I know I can use the maven-replacer-plugin by replacing `1.0.0` with some token (say `$my_version`). Then, I could use this token to replace the value on the fly.

However, I don't want to use the token value; what I need is to replace all the text after the `=` (equal sign).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maven-antrun-plugin` to replace a string in the source code. Declare `resources` and `plugin` as below:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <replace token="<strToBeReplaced>" value="<yourValue>" dir="target/classes">
                            <include name="**/*.properties" />
                        </replace>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

Run `mvn clean install` the string/token in the properties file will be replaced by the value given in pom.xml

Comment: Thanks Mithun for the reply. But my problem is I don't know the token value "strToBeReplaced". It could be anything. All I know that I need to replace anything after "version=x.x.x", i.e. x.x.x could be anything.